# Hooks in R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Given an R markdown document, the output of code chunks when the document is knitted can be customized by using the

```
knitr:knit_hooks
```

object and modifying the `chunk` hook.
However, hooks do not seem to work when the chunk is run interactively, i.e. by doing command+option+c.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect as knitr::knit_hooks but for R markdown chunks that are run interactively?

Comment: I assume you want to run this in Rstudio?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently unsupported.

For the specific case of the `render` hook there’s a feature request and [a GithHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1626) tracking this.